# How to handle slow page loading in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework, testcase

In my Robot framework test case, I have following code snippet to load page and check whether page is successfully loading or not.

```
Go To  ${href}
Wait For Condition    return document.readyState=="complete"    5
Wait For Condition    return document.visibilityState=="visible"    5
Wait Until Page Does Not Contain         404 page not found    5
```

But, in some cases, `Go To  ${href}` takes around 3 min to load a page.

In Robot-framework, Is there any way to skip the page loading and retry if loading time is exceeded particular time?

Answer (score 0):

There is keyword in the BuiltIn libarary called `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` which can be used for retry.

You can give a 1 min timeout to your navigation keyword and run it a maximum 5 times with the afore mentioned keyword for example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tired this also, when i checked the log file for time taken for each keywords, for some url, Go To  ${href} took 5 min without retrying. My objective here is if page loading time (Time taken for Go To  ${href} takes much time), i have to exit from that keyword. Couldn't achieve this yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default timeout for the selenium framework with "Set Selenium Timeout" and then execute the "Go To ...", that will prevent you from waiting for 3 min

If you want to repeat the Go To until it doesn't fail you can use the "Wait Until Keyword Succeeds" as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tired this also, by default selenium framework timeout is 5 sec. even for that value, Go To <url> keyword was keep on running until complete page is getting loaded which cause the high execution time for a test suite. So i want to stop the Go TO {url} url if it reaches particular time.

Comment: I used Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    3    30s    Go to ${href} also Set Selenium Timeout as well